# Unable to print values based on key in Hashmap

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, user-input, do-while

I'm having trouble making option 7 work in my code (i.e. choice == 7), the one that outputs a student's set of quiz scores. 
When I run the program, it simply asks for jumps back to the original set of choices. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
package studentquizgrades;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class StudentQuizGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Student> map = new HashMap<>();

    addStudent(map);

}

private static void addStudent(Map<String, Student> map) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean finish = false;


    do {
        System.out.println("Please choose an option: ");
        System.out.println("Add student and quizzes - 1, Get all quiz scores - 2, Get highest quiz score- 3, ");
        System.out.println("Get lowest quiz score - 4, Get class average - 5, View a list of all students - 6");
        System.out.println("Get a student's quiz scores - 7, Quit - 8");
        int choice = userInput.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            System.out.println("How many students would you like to add?");
            int numberOfStudents = userInput.nextInt();
            for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfStudents; counter++) {

                System.out.println("ENTER NAME");
                Scanner addName = new Scanner(System.in);
                String name = (addName.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Enter First Quiz Score");
                Scanner addQuiz1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int quiz1 = (addQuiz1.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter Second Quiz Score");
                Scanner addQuiz2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int quiz2 = (addQuiz2.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter Third Quiz Score");
                Scanner addQuiz3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int quiz3 = (addQuiz3.nextInt());
                Student student = new Student(name, quiz1, quiz2, quiz3);
                map.put(student.getKey(), student);

            }

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            for (String currentKey : keySet) {
                Student student = map.get(currentKey);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(currentKey);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(student.getQuizGrades()));
                System.out.println();

            }

        } else if (choice == 3) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            int max = 0;
            String maxName = null;

            for (String currentKey : keySet) {

                Student student = map.get(currentKey);
                int[] scores = student.getQuizGrades();

                for (int counter = 1; counter < scores.length; counter++) {
                    if (scores[counter] > max) {
                        max = scores[counter];
                        maxName = currentKey;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The highest quiz score was " + max + "; his/her name is " + maxName);
            System.out.println();

        } else if (choice == 4) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            String minName = null;

            for (String currentKey : keySet) {
                Student student = map.get(currentKey);
                int index = 0;
                int[] scores = student.getQuizGrades();

                for (int counter = 0; counter < scores.length; counter++) {
                    if (scores[counter] < min) {
                        minName = currentKey;
                        min = scores[counter];

                    }

                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The lowest quiz score was " + min + "; his or her name is " + minName);
            System.out.println();

        } else if (choice == 5) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            int[] allGrades;
            int sum = 0;
            int counter2 = 0;
            for (String currentKey : keySet) {
                Student student = map.get(currentKey);
                int[] scores = student.getQuizGrades();
                for (int counter = 0; counter < scores.length; counter++) {
                    int j = scores[counter];
                    sum = sum + j;
                    counter2++;
                }

            }
            int average = sum / counter2;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The class average is: " + average);
            System.out.println("");
        } else if (choice == 6) {
            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("List of students: ");
            for (String currentKey : keySet) {
                Student student = map.get(currentKey);

                System.out.println(currentKey);

            }
        } 
        else if(choice == 7){


            Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please enter a student's name: ");
            String studentName = userInput.nextLine();
            for (String currentKey : keySet) {

                Student student = map.get(currentKey);

                if(studentName == currentKey){

                    System.out.println(currentKey + "'s quiz scores:");
                    int [] quizArray = student.getQuizGrades();
                    for(int counter1 = 0; counter1 < quizArray.length; counter1++ ){

                        System.out.println(quizArray[counter1]);

                    }
                }

            }
        }


        else if (choice == 8) {
            finish = true;
            break;
        }
    } while (finish == false);
}
}

package studentquizgrades;

public class Student {
private String key;
private int grade1;
private int grade2;
private int grade3;

    public Student(String key, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3){
        this.key = key;
        this.grade1 = grade1;
        this.grade2 = grade2;
        this.grade3 = grade3;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public int[] getQuizGrades(){
       int [] anArray = {grade1, grade2, grade3};
       return anArray;
    }

    public int getAverageScore(){
        int average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3)/3;
        return average;
    }
```

}

Comment: Well you can't compare strings using == like this: `if(studentName == currentKey){`  Gotta use the 'equals' method:  `string.equals( otherString );`

Comment: Ah ok, I knew something was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: After selecting 7, does it let you enter the student's name? What is the exact output?

Comment: Also, that loop looks wrong.  You should be able to just use `map.get( studentName );` but I didn't analyze the code carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix `scanner.nextInt()` and `scanner.nextLine()`.
When you call `scanner.nextInt()` and then you call `scanner.nextLine()`, `scanner.nextLine()` returns the remain of the current line of the input entered by `scanner.nextInt()`, that is an empty String. And that before you may enter anything.
That's why you loop to the original set of choices.

You should avoid to chain`next()` and `nextLine()`. Try to use only the one or the other one.

Besides, the code in the  `else if(choice == 7)` block compares String values with `==` and besides this comparison is even not required since you perform a loop on the map of students to retrieve the student while you have a Map that may retrieve the information in a straight way :

```
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Please enter a student's name: ");
String studentName = userInput.next();
for (String currentKey : keySet) {

     Student student = map.get(currentKey);

     if(studentName == currentKey){

             System.out.println(currentKey + "'s quiz scores:");
             int [] quizArray = student.getQuizGrades();
              for(int counter1 = 0; counter1 < quizArray.length; counter1++ ){
                      System.out.println(quizArray[counter1]);
               }
      }

}
```

You could do simply :

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Please enter a student's name: ");
String studentName = userInput.next();

Student student = map.get(studentName);
if (student!=null){
      System.out.println(studentName + "'s quiz scores:");
      int[] quizArray = student.getQuizGrades();
      for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < quizArray.length; counter1++) {
         System.out.println(quizArray[counter1]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, in the context of my code, what modifications can I make so that the user can input a student's name and then identify the quiz scores?

Comment: Try to replace nextLine() by next()

Comment: You have several  other important changes to do. I updated my post.

Comment: "Besides, the code in the else if(choice == 7) block compares String values with == " This refers to the wrong if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if (studentName == currentKey)` use `if (studentName.equals(currentKey)`. You should **always** compare strings with `equals(...)`, because `==` only checks the equality of **references**, not the objects itself. As `studentName` and `current` key are two independent instances, they are never equal in a comaprison with `==` as their references differ.

You should try to refactor your code, as there are multiple issues. As [@markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) already pointed out, your loop is unnecessary and the critical `if` statement is not needed at all.

```
for (String currentKey : keySet) {
    Student student = map.get(currentKey);
    if(studentName == currentKey){
        //...
    }
}
```

This can be reduced to the following code as you deal with a map. That is the point of a map, not having to iterate through all elements, but to use a key to directly access an element.

```
Student student = map.get(currentKey);
if (student != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, you should call `nextLine();` after `int choice = userInput.nextInt();` [(and other `next...(...);` calls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo), because they do not consume the newline character. Otherwise `studentName = userInput.nextLine();` will only contain the newline character leftover from last call to `nextInt()...;`.